How can I use Bootstrap validation with HTMX hx-post requests
I have a project which uses Bootstrap frontend toolkit. Bootstrap supports HTML5 form validation with custom styles. To use this feature a form need to have the novalidate attribute:
<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="validationCustom01" class="form-label">First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" value="Mark" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Looks good!
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

I also use HTMX to send AJAX requests. Unfortunately if the attribute novalidate is set the AJAX request is executed even if some required input elements are not set. I think this is because of the novalidate attribute. If I remove this attribute the form is validated and the AJAX request isn't send. But in this case the custom style form Bootstrap isn't used for the validation result.
<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" hx-post="/request/123" novalidate>
...
</form>

Any ideas how to get Bootstrap validation and HTMX requests work together?

You can check the htmx:configRequest property and handle it to prevent the form from being submitted:
<form class="needs-validation"
    hx-post="{{ url_for('profile.change_user_info') }}"
    hx-trigger="submit"
    hx-target="#profile_content"
    hx-swap="outerHTML"
    novalidate
>

JS:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

    forms.forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }
        }, false);
    });

    document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', function (event) {
        const form = event.target.closest('form');
        if (form && !form.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }
    });
});

